# MapProxy dosen't display certain uncached tiles

Tags: geoserver, openstreetmap, wms, wmts, mapproxy

I face an unnormal behavior of MapProxy on client.

The way of spatial data looks like: |PostgreSQL| --> |GeoServer|wms request| --> |seeding tiles|MapProxy|wmts request| -->|Fronend(OL6)|

My seed.yaml looks like:

```
seeds:
  myseed1:
    caches: [ps_osm_cache]
    levels: [0,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
    refresh_before:
        time: 2019-12-04T12:35:00
```

[image: dir with cache looks correctly:]

But some tiles on 13-14 levels:

12 (all is ok):

[image]

13 is not (water styles are dead):

[image]

14 bad again (but some new correct tiles):

[image]

and from 15 to 19 all is OK!

What is wrong? It isn't mapproxy cache of 13-19, cause I tryied remove all tiles, and did seeding again... result hadn't achived...
And It isn't 'no data' problem, cause wms from geoserver and PostgreSQL info show that all is ok.. I really don't understand what the reason..

Comment: please look in the log files and add any relevant error messages to your question using the [edit] button

Comment: ok, I will do it

Comment: @IanTurton But before I have to ativate logs

Comment: @IanTurton no one error or warning message ...

Comment: I face the same issue too, and I think it is something to do with the recent version of MapProxy.